# Not able to understand a javascript code also a use case

Tags: javascript, html

I was just experimenting with some javascript code on JsFiddle and then I was completely blank being not able to understand a code.
JsFiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/K3w7c/

**Question**:What does following mean?

```
window.onload=function(){
var clicked = function(){
    alert('i am hit');
}
}
```

and how to do I call the "clicked" function from a code something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="clicked();">Hit me</a>
```

**please note**: I know if the function definition was outside the `window.onload` then it will work but **I am really not able to understand the use case when would I have a function declaration inside `window.onload`** and if there is such a declaration then how do I call it.

thanks.

Comment: Learn about "scope" and "closures", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: I am really not sure what is the issue with the question , so many negative votes. it was a genuine question that I was not able to understand a piece of code.

Comment: It's pretty simple, may be that's why users are downvoting you for the lack of research efforts, it's a function which is invoked `onclick` event, that's it..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K3w7c/1/

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alien at least you responded constructively. When you say "it's a function which is invoked onclick event" but I see a error on console when I hit on the anchor link. please can you elaborate further.

Comment: The question doesn't look too bad, I didn't downvote, but there are probably many duplicates.

Comment: @Mr.Alien please can you change the value on the top right drop down to "onload" on your jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use `clicked` function you need to declare it on `window`, and if you want to declare `clicked` on `load` event, this approach can be used:

```
window.onload=function(){
    clicked = function(){
        alert('i am hit');
    }
}
```

`clicked` is defined on `window` by omitting the `var` keyword

Comment: @amr1r_5h, any use case where in such approach is useful. i.e creating a function once window is loaded.

Comment: declaring `event handlers` in `load` event is not common, because these declaration doesn't need to any asset be loaded before, `onload` is used when you need to do an operation when all assets has loaded

Answer (score 1):

The var **clicked**  is a local variable not a global variable, so you can't visit it in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `clicked` function global like;

```
window.onload=function(){
  clicked = function(){
    alert('i am hit');
}
}
```

Just remove the `var`. That will do.

Answer (score -1):

onload is an event which fires when an object has finished loading.

It's usually used to ensure everything is ready before running javascript.

A common use case is when you are running code which uses external libraries which need to be fetched:

```
window.onload(function(){ 
 thirdPartyLib.init();
});
```

Comment: question is not about `onload` event

Comment: yup, I know that. but my question is will there be any use case where in I will have a function declaration inside the onload?